# Products of a particular shop not showing up in an online mall

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, multi-tenant

Am developing a mall, the homepage displays all shops in the mall.

I am unable to show products of a specific shop when a visitor clicks on different shop

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Shop(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Product(models.Model):
    shop_name = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Below is my views in the app

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Shop, Product


def index(request):
    shops = Shop.objects.all()
    context = {"shops":shops}
    return render(request, 'index.html',context)


def shop_details(request, pk):
    shop_details = get_object_or_404(Shop, pk)
    products = Product.objects.filter(id=pk)
    context = {'shop_details':shop_details, 'products':products}
    return render(request, 'shop_detail.html', context)


def shop_product_details(request):
    return render(request, 'shop-product-detail.html', {})
```

below are my urls
***urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    
    path('all_shops/', views.index, name='index'),
    path('shop_details/<int:pk>/', views.shopdetails, name='shop_details'),
    path('shop_product_details/', views.shop_product_details, name='shop_product_details'),
]
```

Below are my templates
**index.html**

```
{% for shop in shops %}
    <div>
        <div>
            <a href="{% url 'shop_details' shop.pk %}">
                <img src="/uploads/{{ shop.shop_logo }}" alt="{{ shop.shop_name }}">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <article>
                <h4 >
                    < a href = "{% url 'shop_details' shop.pk %}" > {{shop.shop_name}} < / a >
                </h4>
                <div>
                    <a href="{% url 'shop_details' shop.pk %}"> Visit Shop</a>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Below page should show details of the shop and show all products within this shop, removed some codes to make it minimal

**shop-detail.html**

```
{% for product in products %}
    <div>
        {{product.shop_name}}
        {{product.product_name}}
        {{product.product_added_on}}
        {{product.product_description}}
        <a href="{% url 'shop_product_details' %}"> View Product</a>
    </div>
    {% empty %}
        <p> No Products available</p>
{%endfor % }
```

I would have wished to use multi tenant as shown here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NsWlUMTfIFo but am unable to implement

Comment: Please see [ask]. As it is this question shows no existing research and mentions no specific problem (error, unexpected output, etc.)

Comment: @Seth where have i gone wrong, have gone through the How to Ask. How should i restructure my question

Comment: "As it is this question shows no existing research and mentions no specific problem (error, unexpected output, etc.)" The main prerequisite for asking a question is that you are encountering a specific problem. "How do I" questions are not specific problems.

Comment: @Seth, i get you let me rephrase the questions, the error is products of a shop are not showing up

Comment: Ok, now could you provide a [mre] that shows the problem?

Comment: @Seth, kindly check the question, is it okay?

Comment: Getting there! If I ran this, it would complain that `mall.models` doesn't exist. Can you give a [mre] that doesn't cause an `ImportError` (but is still minimal and reproducible)?

Comment: @Seth, made changes, any other recommendations

Comment: Still causes import error. `.models` doesn't exist for me.

Comment: @Seth have added models

Comment: ok but now it's not a [mre]!

Comment: `'shop_details/<int:pk>/'` I assume the shop's pk is passed in this url yet you write `products = Product.objects.filter(id=pk)`... you should be writing `products = Product.objects.filter(shop_name=shop_details)`

Comment: @Seth, have deleted some codes, still not minimal example?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat have changed to `products = Product.objects.filter(shop_name=shop_details)` still not showing up

Comment: @miruni could you please show us your templates  it will be more easier to help ?

Comment: @amadousow have added the templates

Comment: is your models.py  complete or you just show a part of your model ?

Comment: try this products = Product.objects.filter(shop_name=pk).

Comment: @amadou sow just showed part of the model

Comment: does  Product.objects.filter(shop_name=pk) works ?

Comment: @amadou not working

Comment: does my answer below works ?

Comment: @amadousow still does not show products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked for me
***views.py***

```
def shop(request, pk):
    template = 'mall/shop-detail.html'
    
    # Display products in a single shop
    shop = Shop.objects.get(id=pk)
    products = shop.product_set.all()
    
    context = {'shop':shop, 'products':products,}
    return render(request, template, context)
```